# How to reference image in NextJS from Strapi API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, strapi

**How to reference images stored in components content types. I have successfully fetch my text data dynamically by using components but not able to do the same with image.I want to show images that I stored in Strapi as Answer_Image with Option_answer in Text Component.Below I am attaching my api response.Please help me out with this.**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 11,
        "attributes": {
            "text": "Which color do you like best?",
            "createdAt": "2022-06-16T15:11:17.425Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-09T08:29:02.862Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-16T15:11:19.025Z",
            "slug": "1",
            "Text": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "Option_answer": "Blue",
                    "Answer_image": {
                        "data": {
                            "id": 14,
                            "attributes": {
                                "name": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Color-blue.JPG",
                                "alternativeText": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Color-blue.JPG",
                                "caption": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Color-blue.JPG",
                                "width": 512,
                                "height": 384,
                                "formats": {
                                    "small": {
                                        "ext": ".JPG",
                                        "url": "/uploads/small_Color_blue_9d367bd795.JPG",
                                        "hash": "small_Color_blue_9d367bd795",
                                        "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                        "name": "small_https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Color-blue.JPG",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "size": 1.42,
                                        "width": 500,
                                        "height": 375
                                    },
                                    "thumbnail": {
                                        "ext": ".JPG",
                                        "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_Color_blue_9d367bd795.JPG",
                                        "hash": "thumbnail_Color_blue_9d367bd795",
                                        "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                        "name": "thumbnail_https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Color-blue.JPG",
                                        "path": null,
                                        "size": 0.46,
                                        "width": 208,
                                        "height": 156
                                    }
                                },
                                "hash": "Color_blue_9d367bd795",
                                "ext": ".JPG",
                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                "size": 1.42,
                                "url": "/uploads/Color_blue_9d367bd795.JPG",
                                "previewUrl": null,
                                "provider": "local",
                                "provider_metadata": null,
                                "createdAt": "2022-06-08T17:58:35.591Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2022-06-08T17:58:35.591Z"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
```